# How can I diagnose random restarts?

Tags: restart

My Macbook Air is randomly restarting — a real problem when I have it set up to give a presentation, and walk to the stage to find it back at the login screen. How can I diagnose the cause?

Answer (score 4):

`Console.app` located in `Applications/Utilities` will display the logs of the system. Inspecting might point you to the reason of the reboots.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I looked at the logs (which are AMAZINGLY ENDLESS — I had no idea of all the work being done) but can't see anything obvious at a point where it is restarting. What should I search for? The only "restart" that showed up in a search was "CGX Restart Session Workspace". Might that be it?